# Using WP_Mail on MacOS 12 (Monterey - M1)

Tags: wp-mail, smtp

On a brand new Macbook running Monterey (M1), as PHP was removed by Apple on OS 12, I have removed all "AMP" preinstalled by Apple and installed HomeBrew "AMP" (with PHP 7.4), which is running perfectly.

Now, as I have setup Wordpress for testing purposes, I am attempting to use Wordpress WP_Mail function, which relies on PHPMailer, which in turn uses PHP Mail command. The latter relies on system specific libraries, and I am bit confused about configuring the correct facility, Mail, SendMail, Mailsend....

Digging the Internet, once upon a time you would achieve this through Postfix or eventually setting up an email account in the System settings for [Mail.app](https://mail.app/) , which I would like to avoid, as I only use web mail on browser and hate to have an email client accessing my account.........

In conclusion, on a Monterey M1 machine, Homebrew "AMP" scenario, is there a way to allow PHPMailer to work, avoiding using [Mail.app](https://mail.app/) account?

Comment: I don't think this is WP specific and should probably better be asked at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) or another sibling site. In the end the question boils down to "How can PHP send mails locally?". Trying to answer it: Does it need to? Locally all my sites aren't sending mails via the internet, instead I'm using Mailhog with [mhsendmail](https://github.com/mailhog/mhsendmail). For WP context: You could install a mail plugin and use real SMTP connection over PHP's `mail()` method. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to achieve testing sending emails from wordpress, installed locally on a mac. Seems to be specific, as other WP users might have faced this configuration issue. BTW I'd rather avoid using plugins for this

Comment: Sending mails to where? Globally, or you just want to know if WP sent the mail and have a look at it?

Comment: Anywhere. I just need to play with the "Send Reset Link" button in the Admin dashboard, which is broken on the production site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I put this function on the functions.php or in a plugin and works for me everywhere, on localhost or in any server. just need to change the strings to your email smtp settings. Only with gmail I could not make it work so far, all the other ones I try it works perfectly.

```php
// Overriding wp smtp email to send smtp emails (no spam emails)
if (! function_exists('email_sender')){
 add_action('phpmailer_init','email_sender');
 function email_sender($mail){
     $mail->SetFrom('myemail@hotmail.org', 'thenameIwant to appear on the emails sended');
     $mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
     $mail->Port = 587;
     $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'STARTTLS';
     $mail->Username = 'myemail@hotmail.org';
     $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
     $mail->IsSMTP();
 }
}
```

then email should work like a charm!  I normally use [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) to do it.

Comment: Thanks mate! I need Gmail BTW, why this is not working on your end?

Comment: Who closed this topic should notice that it was a specific question to Wordpress, based on the upvotes!

Comment: with custom company emails, hotmail it all works wonderful, when I use my gmail, I change the port, smtpauth, smtpsecure, smtphost, all the definitions to gmail, but then I'm not receiving the emails. I really do not know why, It must be wrong configurations, once every other email works great. if someone has the right configurations for gmail smtp, please share them. would be very appreciated

Comment: Tiago, I had that filter in my setup already, and it works. You miss 
    `$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";`

Comment: `add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_example',5 );

function my_phpmailer_example( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; // Force it to use Username and Password to authenticate
    $phpmailer->Port = 587;
    $phpmailer->Username = 'me@adomain.com';
    $phpmailer->Password = 'thepassword';

    // Additional settings…
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // Choose SSL or TLS, if necessary for your server
    $phpmailer->From = "me@adomain.com";
    //$phpmailer->FromName = "A mailer service";
}`

Comment: I thought it could be configurations, I always had choosen STARTTLS, it seems to gmail its better TLS. Thanks!